# Get total and max of subgroup in dax?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I aim to get the **total** and the **max** for each C% group but I am unable…

Given the below data, I would like to do  Total/MAX (per C% group), that is:

- for C1    50/50
- for C2    35/25
- for C3    35/20

[image]

Is it possible to do it within a single measure?

Answer (score 0):

To find `Total & Max` for each group, it can be done by using `calculate` measure again and using `variable` for better view, below is the formula:

```
Percentage = 
var total = CALCULATE(SUM(TAX[Value]),
                FILTER(TAX,TAX[Main] = EARLIER(TAX[Main])),
                    FILTER(TAX,TAX[Subgroup1] = EARLIER(TAX[Subgroup1])))
var maxV = CALCULATE(MAX(TAX[Value]),
                FILTER(TAX,TAX[Main] = EARLIER(TAX[Main])),
                    FILTER(TAX,TAX[Subgroup1] = EARLIER(TAX[Subgroup1])))
return
total/maxV
```

**The table with add column:**

[image]